# Ordered Binary trees, printing strings in ascending order using tree sort

Tags: java, sorting, binary-tree

Okay my aim is to read line by line from the standard input(a single String on each line),insert them into a tree , then sort the strings in ascending order and print them out.It prints

```
java.util.ArrayList$Itr@659e0bfd
```

QUESTION:
What does this mean

```
return elementsList.iterator();
```

?How can I use it in my main?

```
public class OBTComparable<Type extends Comparable<Type>>
{
  ... 
  private Type data;
  ...
  public Iterator elementsAscending()
  {
    ArrayList<Type> elementsList = new ArrayList<Type>();
    addElementsAscending(elementsList);
    return elementsList.iterator();
  } // elementsAscending

  private void addElementsAscending(List elementsList)
  {
    if (!empty)
    { 
      left.addElementsAscending(elementsList);
      elementsList.add(data); 
      right.addElementsAscending(elementsList);
    } // if
  } // addElementsAscending
```

Now the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  OBTComparable<String> obt = new OBTComparable<String>();
  BufferedReader reader
    = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  try
  {
    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      obt.insert(line);
    obt.elementsAscending();
    System.out.println(obt.elementsAscending()); 
    ////// NEED HELP HERE /////


  } catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e); };
```

Comment: You need to implement you own BST?

Comment: Yes, because i am a beginner.If u have any suggestions please share with me.I want to learn how to implement it.Its probably a couple of lines of code but ...

Comment: If you make it a BST, then an in-order traversal of the tree will give you the sorted order.  It's hard to tell, but it doesn't look like you have a valid BST here.  Just maintain BST rules when inserting, and then have a method that does a in-order traversal of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I fixed it.

```
String line;
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      obt.insert(line);
    Iterator<String> t = obt.elementsAscending();
    while (t.hasNext())
    {
      String item = t.next();
      System.out.println(item);
    }
```

Feels good now :D .